# Toggle switch shows no animation when using it to call a function

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular building a website and I created a toggle switch. [toggle switch picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgRTf.png)

My idea was simple. When the switch is clicked , it would call a function called "power" with parameter called "d.key"  in the page's .ts file. So i added this into toggle switch's html. [HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDdP1.png)

This method works, the function was successfully called every time i click on it, but i found that my toggle switch is frozen, by frozen i mean when i click on it, it won't show me the switch animation, like is never been clicked. ["Tho the function is called, the switch remains like this"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CkqD.png)

How do i solve this, any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [ngClass] like:

```
[ngClass]="{ 'checked': value }"
```

and change the styling based on .checked class.

For detailed implementation, follow this article: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-custom-form-controls-with-reactive-forms-and-ngmodel